# How to display bold or change color of certain text in CONTENT-TYPE : image/png?

Tags: php, image, content-type

I have string like "K for `<b>King</b`>". I have converted it to image now i have to bold that "King" or change to any color. Is it possible?

```
   header ('Content-Type: image/png');
    $string         = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. <b>It was popularised in the 1960s<b> with the release of <b>Letraset<b> sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.";       

    $fontSize       = 14;
    $lines          = explode("\n", wordwrap($string, 100, "\n"));

    $margin         = 5;
    $heightImage    = count($lines) * $maring  + $margin;

    $image  = imagecreatetruecolor (400, $heightImage);
    $white  = imagecolorallocate ($image,255,255,255);
    $black  = imagecolorallocate ($image,0,0,0);
    $blue   = imagecolorallocate ($image,0,0,266);

    $fontPath = '../css/fonts/font/OpenSans-Regular.ttf';
    imagefill($image,0,0,$white);

    foreach ($lines as $line) {

        imagettftext($image, $fontSize, 0, 0, $margin, $black, $fontPath, $line);
        $margin += 5      
    }


    imagepng ($image);
    imagedestroy($image);
```

Comment: How did you convert text to image?

Comment: question edited what do you think about it.. ???